# Advanced filtered search: Matrix fields and arrays

Tags: matrix, users, search, filter, array

Having scoured the forums for similar questions of [which](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4571/building-results-from-advanced-search-form?rq=1) [there](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/9499/filter-entries-by-multiple-categories) are [a few](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/9081/how-to-filter-entries-by-clicking-multiple-categories-on-front-end/9083#9083), I'm still struggling to figure out my specific usecase. I have 4 filters and a search box (which searches a [custom tag field](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/11749/limit-search-results-for-users-by-tag-and-limit-to-5-tags)) to filter `craft.users` in a group. 3 of the filters are matrix fields, 2 of the filters are posted as an array.

1. Gender seems to be working fine:

   - The first option’s gender value is empty “”, which seems to work and return both genders if selected. Is this fine, or should I be checking if a value has been posted? And if so, would I need to use [a ternary operator to `set` a default array](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/4573/3888) for both male and female values?
2. How do I add a Matrix field into the `craft.users` object syntax?

   - Is this even possible? I can imagine setting something like `maxPrice: "<= #{maxPrice}"` for a standard number field, but have no idea how I'd do so for a number field within a Matrix block:

     - i.e. `craft.users.profilePricing.type('details').session`

I'm using matrix fields as they separate related chunks of data better, the specific ones I need to search are limited to [number fields](https://craftcms.com/docs/number-fields), [dropdown](https://craftcms.com/docs/dropdown-fields) and [checkboxes](https://craftcms.com/docs/checkboxes-fields). All of which only allow 1 block. For now at least, the filters should match all criteria with `and` logic.

#### Filters

Here is an example of the filter options:

```
<select name="gender">
  <option value="">Male and female</option>
  <option value="male">Male</option>
  <option value="female">Female</option>
</select>
<div class="form-group">
  <input id="maxPrice" type="number" name="maxPrice" min="0" max="100" step="5">
  <label for="maxPrice"><small>Maximum session price</small></label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="skype" name="sessions[]" checked> Skype
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="chat" name="sessions[]" checked> Live web chat
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="phone" name="sessions[]" checked> Telephone
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="email" name="sessions[]" checked> Email
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="office" name="hours[]" checked> Office hours
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="overtime" name="hours[]" checked> Out of hours
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="weekends" name="hours[]" checked> Weekends
  </label>
</div>
```

#### Results

And the unfinished code for the search results:

```
<h1>Search Results</h1>

{% set tags = craft.request.getParam('tags') %}
{% set gender = craft.request.getParam('gender') %}
{% set maxPrice = craft.request.getParam('maxPrice') %}
{% set sessions = craft.request.getParam('sessions') %}
{% set hours = craft.request.getParam('hours') %}

{% set results = craft.users({
  group: 'verified',
  search: "tagsSpecialismSearchable:#{tags}",
  gender: gender,
}) %}

{% set users = shuffle(results) %}

{% if users|length %}
  <p>{{ users|length }} results:</p>

  {% include '_includes/counsellors/profile.html' %}
{% else %}
  <p>Your search for “{{ tags }}” didn’t return any results.</p>
{% endif %}
```

[image: Search filters]